# Android Web Console: UncaughtReferenceError: Worker is not defined

Tags: javascript, android

I'm pretty new about javascript. after a long search I couldn't find why but looks like popular browsers does somework about this definition new Worker("BarcodeWorker.js") as their base js support but Android WebView. Orginal code is from Eddie Larsson barcode reader on github. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>BarcodeReader</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="container">
        <img width="640" height="480" src="about:blank" alt="" id="picture">
        <input id="Take-Picture" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" />
        <p id="textbit"></p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var takePicture = document.querySelector("#Take-Picture"),
        showPicture = document.querySelector("#picture");
        Result = document.querySelector("#textbit");
        Canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        Canvas.width=640;
        Canvas.height=480;
        var resultArray = [];
        ctx = Canvas.getContext("2d");
        var workerCount = 0;
        function receiveMessage(e) {
            if(e.data.success === "log") {
                console.log(e.data.result);
                return;
            }
            workerCount--;
            if(e.data.success){
                var tempArray = e.data.result;
                for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
                    if(resultArray.indexOf(tempArray[i]) == -1) {
                        resultArray.push(tempArray[i]);
                    }
                }
                Result.innerHTML=resultArray.join("<br />");
            }else{
                if(resultArray.length === 0 && workerCount === 0) {
                    Result.innerHTML="Decoding failed.";
                }
            }
        }
                    //Where the issue starts
        var script='';
        var DecodeWorker = new Worker("DecoderWorker.js");
        var RightWorker = new Worker("DecoderWorker.js");
        var LeftWorker = new Worker("DecoderWorker.js");
        var FlipWorker = new Worker("DecoderWorker.js");
        DecodeWorker.onmessage = receiveMessage;
        RightWorker.onmessage = receiveMessage;
        LeftWorker.onmessage = receiveMessage;
        FlipWorker.onmessage = receiveMessage;
        if(takePicture && showPicture) {
            takePicture.onchange = function (event) {
                var files = event.target.files
                if (files && files.length > 0) {
                    file = files[0];
                    try {
                        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
                        var imgURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                        showPicture.src = imgURL;
                        URL.revokeObjectURL(imgURL);
                        DecodeBar()
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        try {
                            var fileReader = new FileReader();
                            fileReader.onload = function (event) {
                                showPicture.src = event.target.result;
                            };
                            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                            DecodeBar()
                        }
                        catch (e) {
                            Result.innerHTML = "Neither createObjectURL or FileReader are supported";
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        function DecodeBar(){
            showPicture.onload = function(){
                ctx.drawImage(showPicture,0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height);
                resultArray = [];
                workerCount = 4;
                Result.innerHTML="";
                DecodeWorker.postMessage({pixels:        ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "normal"});
                RightWorker.postMessage({pixels: ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "right"});
                LeftWorker.postMessage({pixels: ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "left"});
                FlipWorker.postMessage({pixels: ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "flip"});
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Web Workers aren't available to you, (and [aren't available in current versions of Opera Mini and the Android browser](http://caniuse.com/webworkers) [but are in mobile Chrome!]).  They're a way to put some resource-intensive tasks in another thread, so your main thread doesn't get held up (useful to prevent the app/page appearing to freeze for a moment).

Luckily, they shouldn't be necessary for your code to work.  You'll need to move the javascript from "DecoderWorker.js" into the scope of your page, and rework/remove the message and onmessage events, instead calling the function(s) copied from the worker directly.

**UPDATE**: Here's a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHtsH/) to get you started.  I just replaced `e.data` with `options` and changed the message events to functions:

```
/* From reader.html */

function receiveMessage(options) {
    if(options.success === "log") {
        console.log(options.result);
        return;
    }
    workerCount--;
    if(options.success){
        var tempArray = options.result;
        for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++) {
            if(resultArray.indexOf(tempArray[i]) == -1) {
                resultArray.push(tempArray[i]);
            }
        }
        Result.innerHTML=resultArray.join("<br />");
    }else{
        if(resultArray.length === 0 && workerCount === 0) {
            Result.innerHTML="Decoding failed.";
        }
    }
}
function DecodeBar(){
    showPicture.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(showPicture,0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height);
        resultArray = [];
        workerCount = 4;
        Result.innerHTML="";
        ReadBarcode({pixels: ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "normal"}, receiveMessage);
        ReadBarcode({pixels: ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "right"}, receiveMessage);
        ReadBarcode({pixels: ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "left"}, receiveMessage);
        ReadBarcode({pixels: ctx.getImageData(0,0,Canvas.width,Canvas.height).data, cmd: "flip"}, receiveMessage);
    }
}

/* From the last onmessage handler in DecoderWorker.js */
function  ReadBarcode(options, callback) {
        Image = {
                data: new Uint8ClampedArray(options.pixels),
                width: 640,
                height: 480
        }
        var availableFormats = ["Code128","Code93","Code39","EAN-13"];
        FormatPriority = [];
        var skipList = [];
        if(typeof options.priority != 'undefined') {
                FormatPriority = options.priority;
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < availableFormats.length; i++) {
                if(FormatPriority.indexOf(availableFormats[i]) == -1) {
                        FormatPriority.push(availableFormats[i]);
                }
        }
        if(typeof options.skip != 'undefined') {
                skipList = options.skip;
        }
        for(var i = 0; i < skipList.length; i++) {
                if(FormatPriority.indexOf(skipList[i]) != -1) {
                        FormatPriority.splice(FormatPriority.indexOf(skipList[i]),1);
                }
        }
        CreateTable();
        switch(options.cmd) {
                case "flip":
                        flipTable();
                        break;
                case "right":
                        rotateTableRight();
                        break;
                case "left":
                        rotateTableLeft();
                        break;
                case "normal":
                        break;        
        }
        var FinalResult = Main();
        if(FinalResult.length > 0) {
                callback({result: FinalResult, success: true});
        } else {
                callback({result: FinalResult, success: false});
        }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly I am a newbie on JS and it looks me like a little bit complicated. Can you tell me how to do it if its simple. Coz DecoderWorker.js a bit long.

Comment: Updated my answer with a real quick fix.  You can see in the fiddle that the entire browser freezes for at least a couple seconds when you upload a barcode now.  There's probably some optimizations you could do to improve that.